# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/shared/GWTBridge

Tags: java, gwt

I'm not sure why but I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/shared/GWTBridge` on `line 60` of [Home.java](https://github.com/ThreaT/jenterprise/blob/master/examples/HelloWorld/src/main/java/com/jenterprise/examples/helloworld/scenario/Home.java).

Steps to reproduce:

1. [clone jenterprise](https://github.com/ThreaT/jenterprise.git) and open jenterprise and HelloWorld projects
2. Build jenterprise then HelloWorld
3. Run HelloWorld -> `com.jenterprise.examples.helloworld.Begin`
4. Go to: http://localhost:8090/examples/HelloWorld/home

What I'm trying to do is use `onModuleLoad()` to **update** the interface after executing some other logic in another method then use `forward(request, response)` to **show** the interface, i.e.

```
public void main(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("Running Home: main(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)");
        onModuleLoad();
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Line 60 is call to method `onModuleLoad();` can you post more complete stacktrace?

Comment: so problem is `final Button sendButton = new Button("Send");`

Answer (score 1):

onModuleLoad() is an EntryPoint method, part of client-side GWT code to be compiled by the GWT compiler. You can't use it server-side.

Comment: Request processing happens on the server while onModuleLoad() is part of client code compiled into JavaScript and executing in browser. It has nothing to do with Filters, or Servlets and it's because you're trying to call it server-side that you're getting your error.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that a required jar is on a build path but not available at runtime. Make sure it is included in WEB-INF/lib folder.